# Is it possible for atom-shell (electron) to use system level API?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromium, atom-editor, electron

Recently, I found atom-shell (https://github.com/atom/electron) an interesting tool to develop cross-platform application.

I want to give it try, but I am not sure whether it could support system API easily, such as accessing a USB disk, or video processing APIs such as H264 decoder/encoder..

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Electron just like Node.js uses V8 (different versions though), this means just as it's the case with Node.js, the JavaScript runtime provides a number of APIs to native APIs (take a look at [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module for example).

Moreover you can write your own [native addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) in C++ and expose them to JS runtime. Just note that if you want to use npm packages with native bindings you have to rebuild them against electron headers as explained [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md).

You could also simply start processes using the [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and communicate with them through the `stdin` and `stdout`.